# OpenCV TypeError: Expected cv::UMat for argument 'src' - What is this?

Tags: python, opencv, typeerror, src

Disclaimer: huge openCV noob

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "lanes2.py", line 22, in
>
> ```
> canny = canny(lane_image)
> ```
>
> File "lanes2.py", line 5, in canny
>
> ```
> gray = cv2.cvtColor(imgUMat, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
> ```
>
> TypeError: Expected cv::UMat for argument 'src'

What exactly is 'src' referring to?

Comment: That is not enough information to debug the error. In short, `src` refers to the input matrix/image that you pass to the function.

Answer (score 61):

`src` is the first argument to `cv2.cvtColor`.

The error you are getting is because it is not the right form. `cv2.Umat()` is functionally equivalent to `np.float32()`, so your last line of code should read:

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(np.float32(imgUMat), cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
```

Answer (score 28):

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.UMat(imgUMat), cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
```

UMat is a part of the [Transparent API (TAPI)](https://www.learnopencv.com/opencv-transparent-api/) than help to write one code for the CPU and OpenCL implementations.

Comment: this gave me this error  `UMat() missing required argument 'ranges' (pos 2)`

Comment: @AmitSharma: Then probably `imgUMat` is not a valid `ndarray`, probably, just `None`.

Answer (score 23):

The following can be used from `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np 
image = np.array(image)
```

Comment: this worked for me (python3.7). 
plotting image was successful and image did not seem corrupt in any way. but still got this error when tried to use cv2.resize(image, (1280, 720)). issue resolved after casting to ndarray using numpy as shown above.

Comment: Important issue: ndarray must be contiguous, so you need to copy it in some cases, or you will get exactly the error from topic title. Or even better, use `np.ascontiguousarray(imgUMat)` as suggested in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68436015/4094574

Answer (score 11):

Not your code is the problem this is perfectly fine:

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(imgUMat, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
```

The problem is that imgUMat is `None` so you probably made a mistake when loading your image:

```
imgUMat = cv2.imread("your_image.jpg")
```

I suspect you just entered the wrong image path.

Answer (score 5):

Convert your image matrix to ascontiguousarray using `np.ascontiguousarray` as bellow:

`gray = cv2.cvtColor(np.ascontiguousarray(imgUMat), cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)`

Comment: Documentation says: "Return a contiguous array in memory (C order)", needed for OpenCV

Comment: Technically, it is not a conversion, it is ensuring, that ndarray will lay in memory contiguously (with copying if needed)

Answer (score 4):

Just add this at start:

```
image = cv2.imread(image)
```

Answer (score 2):

Is `canny` your own function? Do you use [Canny](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=canny#canny) from OpenCV inside it? If yes check if you feed suitable argument for `Canny` - first `Canny` argument should meet following criteria:

- type: `<type 'numpy.ndarray'>`
- dtype: `dtype('uint8')`
- being single channel or simplyfing: *grayscale,* that is 2D array, i.e. its `shape` should be 2-`tuple` of `int`s (`tuple` containing exactly 2 integers)

You can check it by printing respectively

```
type(variable_name)
variable_name.dtype
variable_name.shape
```

Replace `variable_name` with name of variable you feed as first argument to `Canny`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a general error, which throws sometimes, when you have **mismatch** between the types of the data you use. E.g I tried to resize the image with opencv, it gave the same error. [Here](https://ai-pool.com/d/typeerror--expected-cv-umat-for-argument--src-) is a discussion about it.

Answer (score 2):

Some dtype are not supported by specific OpenCV functions. For example inputs of dtype np.uint32 create this error. Try to convert the input to a supported dtype (e.g. np.int32 or np.float32)

Answer (score 1):

that is referring to the expected dtype of your image 
"image".astype('float32') should solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I have this error when [videostream](https://github.com/jrosebr1/imutils/blob/master/imutils/video/videostream.py) from [imutils](https://github.com/jrosebr1/imutils) package doesn't recognize frame or give an empty frame. In that case, solution will be figuring out why you have such a bad frame or use a standard VideoCapture(0) method from opencv2

Comment: video capture(0) can't recognize frame due to bad camera ..isn't it???? Please clear this doubt

Answer (score 0):

I got round thid by writing/reading to a file. I guessed cv.imread would put it into the format it needed. This code for anki Vector SDK program but you get the idea.

```
tmpImage = robot.camera.latest_image.raw_image.save('temp.png')         
pilImage = cv.imread('temp.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

**If using ImageGrab**

Verify that your image is not a 0x0 area due to an incorrect `bbox`.

Answer (score 0):

Verify the application root folder is the same as the file you are attempting to run.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using byte object instead of reading from file you can convert your image to numpy array like this

```
image = numpy.array(Image.open(io.BytesIO(image_bytes)))
```