# Resize Function Error in OpenCV in Python 3.6.5?

Tags: python, opencv, resize

```
frame = cv2.resize(frame,None,fx=scaling_factor,fy=scaling_factor,interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)


TypeError: Expected cv::UMat for argument 'src'
```

Why this is error is occurring as the syntax of resize is right and UMAT is basically used for cvtColor?

Comment: See you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54249728/opencv-typeerror-expected-cvumat-for-argument-src-what-is-this/54251094#54251094