# I do not understand my error in my code :"TypeError: UMat() missing required argument 'ranges' (pos 2) "

Tags: python, opencv

I'm following a lesson about OpenCV to see if something moved on a camera. When I test it, it doesn't work and it says:

> TypeError: UMat() missing required argument 'ranges' (pos 2)

I have already referenced this post, but have not been able to solve my problem: [OpenCV TypeError: Expected cv::UMat for argument 'src' - What is this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54249728/opencv-typeerror-expected-cvumat-for-argument-src-what-is-this)

```
import cv2

def fram_diff(prev_frame, cur_frame, next_frame):

    diff_frames_1=cv2.absdiff(next_frame, cur_frame)
    diff_frames_2=cv2.absdiff(cur_frame, prev_frame)
    return cv2.bitwise_and(diff_frames_1, diff_frames_2)

def get_frame(cap, scaling_factor):

    frame = cap.read() 
    frame = cv2.resize(cv2.UMat(frame), None, fx=scaling_factor, fy=scaling_factor, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

    return gray

if __name__=='__main__':

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    scaling_factor=0.5
    prev_frame = get_frame(cap, scaling_factor)
    cur_frame = get_frame(cap, scaling_factor)
    next_frame = get_frame(cap, scaling_factor)
    while True:
        cv2.imshow('Object Movement', fram_diff(prev_frame,cur_frame, next_frame))
        prev_frame=cur_frame
        cur_frame=next_frame
        next_frame=get_frame(cap, scaling_factor)
        key=cv2.waitKey(10)

        if key==27:
            break
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The errors that I have are:

```
line 19, in <module>
    prev_frame = get_frame(cap, scaling_factor)

line 12, in get_frame
    frame = cv2.resize(cv2.UMat(frame), None, fx=scaling_factor, fy=scaling_factor, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)

TypeError: UMat() missing required argument 'ranges' (pos 2)
```

I just found what was wrong! It was in the function get_frame.

To correct my code I have replace the line:

```
frame = cap.read()
```

by the line

```
ret, frame = cap.read()
```

Comment: Check that frame was readed correctly. May be it is empty

Comment: When i print it it print an array with '0' but it doesn't print the entire array. But i found a solution.