# python opencv cv2.threshold( ) , TypeError: Expected cv::UMat for argument 'mat'

Tags: python, opencv

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

imgfile = 'mi.jpg'
img = cv2.imread(imgfile,0)

tmp = img.copy()
kernel_sharpening = np.array([[-1,-1,-1],[-1,9,-1],[-1,-1,-1]])

tmp1 = cv2.pyrDown(tmp)  # down sampleing
tmp2 = cv2.GaussianBlur(tmp1,(3,3),0)   # bluring
tmp3 =cv2.filter2D(tmp2,-1,kernel_sharpening) # sharping

tmp3 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY,15,2)


cv2.imshow('threshold',tmp3)
cv2.waitKey()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The code above works well. However, the code below does not work.

Above cv2.adaptiveThreshold(), below cv2.threshold()

The openvv version is 4.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

imgfile = 'mi.jpg'
img = cv2.imread(imgfile,0)

tmp = img.copy()
kernel_sharpening = np.array([[-1,-1,-1],[-1,9,-1],[-1,-1,-1]])

tmp1 = cv2.pyrDown(tmp)  # down sampleing
tmp2 = cv2.GaussianBlur(tmp1,(3,3),0)   # bluring
tmp3 =cv2.filter2D(tmp2,-1,kernel_sharpening) # sharping
tmp3 = cv2.threshold(tmp3,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

cv2.imshow('threshold',tmp3)
cv2.waitKey()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "down.py", line 26, in
>    cv2.imshow('threshold',tmp3) TypeError: Expected cv::UMat for
>   argument 'mat'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OpenCV TypeError: Expected cv::UMat for argument 'src' - What is this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54249728/opencv-typeerror-expected-cvumat-for-argument-src-what-is-this)

Comment: note that in the above you are threshholding `img` and below you are thershholding `tmp3`

Comment: If you read the documentation of [`cv2.threshold`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#gae8a4a146d1ca78c626a53577199e9c57) you'll notice that it returns a tuple `(retval, dst)` where the second element is the result image. You're feeding the whole tuple to `imshow` which only expects to get an image... that obviously won't work.

Comment: @Nuzhny IMHO it's not a dupe of that one although the message looks similar (also that questions seem pretty poor in the first place). See my observation above. Passing in some garbage confuses the part of bindings that maps python objects to C++.. sometimes this can result in rather confusing error messages.

Comment: Specifically, you will always get errors based on the last attempt at argument or overload resolution. Here it first tries to map the tuple to a `cv::Mat`, which fails, so it proceeds to try to map it to `cv::UMat`, which also fails. There are no more options, so you get an error about `UMat`. Similarly with overload resolution where none of the overloads match, you will always get an error about the last overload it tried...

Answer (score 1):

threshold() returns a tuple...[image: How Docs Work]