# TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'lowerb' - What is it?

Tags: numpy, typeerror, opencv, python

Hey guys I got that error I don't know what it is about, someone can help me?

```
for i in range(numColor):
        globals()["block_all_but_part_color" + str(i+1)]= cv2.inRange(grayscale_image,
                                                                     globals(["min_grayscale_for_color_" + str(i+1)],
                                                                     globals(["max_grayscale_for_color_" + str(i+1)])
```

Comment: Did you try this?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54249728/opencv-typeerror-expected-cvumat-for-argument-src-what-is-this

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change the second and third arg datatype.

```
arg1 = globals(["min_grayscale_for_color_" + str(i+1).

arg1 = np.array(arg1, np.float32)
```

and the same to arg2.