# Getting the error TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'src' while processing images

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, pycharm, ocr

I am getting an error in this code

```
def pre_processing(img):
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img = cv2.equalizeHist(img)
    img = img / 255
    return img
    
while True:
    success, img_original = cap.read()
    img = np.asarray(img_original)
    img = cv2.resize(img, (32, 32))
    img = pre_processing(img)
    cv2.imshow("Processsed Image", img)
    img = img.reshape(1, 32, 32, 1)
```

I get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/test.py", line 27, in 
> img = cv2.resize(img,(32,32))
> TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'src'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenCV TypeError: Expected cv::UMat for argument 'src' - What is this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54249728/opencv-typeerror-expected-cvumat-for-argument-src-what-is-this)

Answer (score 0):

> i dont know whats wrong with this coding

- You need to analyze your code step-by-step
- The first line of your code:

  - ```py
    while True
    ```
  - I would suggest use `cap.isOpened()` where `cap` variable is your `VideoCapture` class object.
  - If your video won't open, then your code won't crash. Otherwise your code will throw error.
- The second line of your code:

  - ```py
    success, imgOriginal = cap.read()
    ```
  - Use `success` variable to check whether the current frame is returned.
  - ```py
    if success:
        .
        .
    ```
- The third line of your code:

  - ```py
    img = np.asarray(img_original)
    ```
  - Use `copy` when you want to keep the original value.
  - ```py
    img = img_original.copy()
    ```
- The fourth line of your code:

  - ```py
    img = pre_processing(img)
    ```
  - You are applying histogram equalization and then normalizing the image.
  - If you normalize the image by `img = img / 255`, `cv2.imshow` will throw an error. Therefore you need to remove the `img = img / 255` line.
- The fifth line of your code:

  - ```py
    cv2.imshow("Processsed Image", img)
    ```
  - You are trying to display the image, therefore you also need to use `waitKey`. The `waitKey` method takes delay as an integer. So you could do:
  - ```py
    cv2.imshow("Processsed Image", img)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
    ```
  - But if you want to close during the display you could do:

    - ```py
      key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
      if key == ord("q"):
          break
      ```
    - If you press `q` the code will terminate.
- The last line of your code:

  - ```py
    img = img.reshape(1, 32, 32, 1)
    ```
  - I assume you are trying to design your code for dataset, but you should reshape after the display.
- Always `release` the `VideoCapture` after exit.

---

Code:

---

```py
import cv2


def pre_processing(img_):
    img_ = cv2.cvtColor(img_, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img_ = cv2.equalizeHist(img_)
    # img_ = img_ / 255
    return img_


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Initialize VideoCature object for Webcam
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    # While webcam opens
    while cap.isOpened():

        # Get the current frame
        success, imgOriginal = cap.read()

        # If the current frame returns successfully
        if success:

            # Copy the original-image
            img = imgOriginal.copy()

            # Resize for 32 x 32
            img = cv2.resize(img, (32, 32))

            # Convert to gray-scale and apply histogram equalization
            img = pre_processing(img)

            # Display the frame
            cv2.imshow("Processsed Image", img)
            key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

            # If `q` is pressed then exit
            if key == ord("q"):
                break
            
    # Reshape
    img = img.reshape(1, 32, 32, 1)
```